# Setting RStudio shortcuts shows wrong keyboard symbol (rectangle)

Tags: r, rstudio, keyboard-shortcuts

Anybody ever encountered this behavior when setting the RStudio-Shortcuts on Windows? I'm using RStudio 1.3.59 but already tried with different versions. So the problem actually is that when using the `Ctrl`-key in combination with any letter, there appears this weird rectangle.

[image]

Comment: Welcome at SO! Please add a little more context around what you are doing to see this broken symbol. In which menu are you, which steps have you taken, which Windows are you using, which language settings are you using on your computer... This look like a missing font...

Comment: Thanks for your ansewer and I'm sorry for my bad question... I'm in the `tools --> modify shortcuts` menu in RStudio. I'm using Windows 10 and german. But you're right, it truly looks like a missing font, but I have no idea on where to start looking:/

Comment: RStudio is using UTF-8

Comment: I checked this on my Win10 NB with German settings and it works as expected. In *Tools > Global options > Appearance >Editor font* I can see `Lucida Console`. How did you install RStudio?

Comment: Thanks for the answers! I downloaded a dailybuild from the rstudio website.

Comment: If you have really downloaded a daily build from github you should better install a "stable" version from https://rstudio.com/products/rstudio/download/#download

Comment: probably you are right. It's just strange as it seemed to work until today in the morning...

Comment: I just downloaded the 1.2.5..... and it works fine. Thanks a lot:)